# Change default browser in Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.4

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10.4-sydney

How can I force **Rad Studio 10.4** to use my default browser (Firefox) instead of **Microsoft Edge** when opening web-based documentation?

Comment: From where do you access this documentation? The menu items on the **Help** menu that open web pages respect my default browser setting (10.3, Win 7, Firefox). But the Welcome page doesn't. This has been reported: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27845

Comment: The Welcome page. I guess, I'll just add this to the list of things that annoy me but that I can't do anything about.

Comment: I thought so. Well, then you can only hope that Embarcadero acts on the Jira issue I linked. You can encourage them to do so by voting for it.

Comment: You can always drag a link from the IDE browser to your Firefox window (to a page, to a tab, to the space between two tabs, or to the `+` button).